# create object type oracle not working

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, object-type

```
CREATE TYPE customer_typ_demo AS OBJECT
( customer_id        NUMBER(6)
, cust_first_name    VARCHAR2(20)
) ;
.
.
.
.
```

Above is the code I used from oracles website, when I hit enter it just gives me another numbered line to type in no matter what I try to type it doesn't break out.  Any suggestions?

Comment: [`create type`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_8001.htm) is a [PL/SQL command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_type.htm). So as Justin says, it needs a `/` - because [that's how you execute PL/SQL in SQL*Plus](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#i1039663).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL*Plus, you would need to put the character `/` on a blank line in order to instruct it to run the code you've typed in.  Otherwise, SQL*Plus doesn't know when your statement is complete.

Comment: Thank you, I thought the ; completed the statement like it does in queries and such

Comment: @user3375693 - That's only for SQL statements.  PL/SQL can contain internal semicolons so terminating the statement when the first semicolon is encountered would be problematic.